# Find number of n-character strings matching a regex?

Tags: c, regex, string

I have a length `n`, an alphabet `A`, and a regular expression `r`. Is it possible to *efficiently* (faster than enumerating all possible strings) find the number of strings, consisting of `n` characters from `A`, that match `r`? If so, how?

C is preferred, but any language is fine!

Comment: Which language?

Comment: This is more mathy than programming. but as long as the length is fixed, there is a number. For instance n is 5, A has 10 letters, and r is `/^.*$/` the result is 10^5.

Comment: If you can express your regex as a DFA, you just need to enumerate all possible paths through the state diagram.

Comment: What regular expression variant?

Comment: The syntax doesn't matter, but the regular expression is an *actual* regular expression (can be recognized by a DFA).